# What is the use of hats in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I want to know what the use of hats in Stack Exchange is.

Comment: I hate hats....

Comment: I want to know the added feature of hats .. that's why am asking this question in this site..

Comment: it's a community game - just for fun. Completely optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're having a little party here to celebrate the end of 2016. It's called [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com) and you can find more details [here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: An end that truly, _truly_ warrants celebrating.

Comment: Many of the hats I have gained are not listed on that page. To be honest, I'm just left scratching my head saying "what the?" Why not explain the hat wherever the site reports I have a hat: "You got the X hat for XYZ"? By the way, I know it's **Winter** bash and all, but for those of us in 40 degree heat... oh, ahem, that's 104 on your continent... yeah, you get my (snowless) drift...

Comment: @youcantryreachingme those are secret hats, and you *will* see them once you have earned them. Those are little puzzles to keep us engaged.